# How to calculate estimated moments with 8 hour work days

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

In my worksheet, I want to calculate estimated end times of processes taking into account workday timeframes.

Assume working days of 8:00 - 17:00 and omit Saturday and Sunday.

So, for example, when I add 4 hours to 14:00 I don't want the result to be 18:00, but 9:00 (3 hours takes you to the end of that workday, the last hour starts the next workday).

Can anyone help me out?

**EDIT -**

With the help of Simon at rcl i managed to adapt his solution to calculate with minutes too. However, there seems to be a problem. When i add

960 minutes to 22-05-15 16:00 the function gives a correct result of 26-05-15 14:00

however, for one hour extra (60 mins) the result changes back to 25-05-15 09:00.

Does anyone see the problem here?

```
Option Explicit

Public Function EndDayTimeM(StartTime As String, Minutes As Double)

On Error GoTo Hell
' start and end hour are fixed here.
' could put them in cells and look them up
Dim startMinute As Long, endMinute As Long, startHour As Long, endHour As Long

startMinute = 480

endMinute = 960 ' was 18

startHour = 8

endHour = 16

Dim calcEnd As Date, start As Date
start = CDate(StartTime)
calcEnd = DateAdd("n", Minutes, start)

If DatePart("h", calcEnd) > endHour Or DatePart("h", calcEnd) <= startHour Then
    ' add 15 hours to get from 17+x to 8+x
    calcEnd = DateAdd("h", 15, calcEnd)  ' corrected

End If

If DatePart("w", calcEnd) = 7 Or DatePart("w", calcEnd) = 1 Then
    ' Sat or Sun: add 2 days
    calcEnd = DateAdd("d", 2, calcEnd)
End If

If DatePart("h", calcEnd) > endHour Or DatePart("h", calcEnd) <= startHour Then
    ' add 15 hours to get from 17+x to 8+x
    calcEnd = DateAdd("h", 15, calcEnd)  ' corrected
End If

EndDayTimeM = calcEnd

GoTo Ret

Hell:
EndDayTimeM = Err.Description
Ret:

End Function
```

Comment: What about if it's a Friday? Do you want 09:00 on Monday?

Comment: @simon at rcl yes please!

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, go to the Developers Ribbon tab and click Visual Basic. [image: Visual Basic window]

Right-click on the VBA Project (outlined in Red) and select Insert and then Module. This will add Module1 to the project below the VBAProject. Double click on Module1.

Select the panel to the right and paste the following code in:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function EndDayTime(StartTime As String, Hours As Double)

    On Error GoTo Hell
    ' start and end hour are fixed here. 
    ' could put them in cells and look them up
    Dim startHour As Long, endHour As Long
    startHour = 8
    
    endHour = 17 ' was 18
    
    Dim calcEnd As Date, start As Date
    start = CDate(StartTime)
    calcEnd = DateAdd("h", Hours, start)
    
    If DatePart("h", calcEnd) > endHour Or DatePart("h", calcEnd) <= startHour Then
        ' add 15 hours to get from 17+x to 8+x
        calcEnd = DateAdd("h", 15, calcEnd) ' corrected
    
    End If
    
    If DatePart("w", calcEnd) = 7 Or DatePart("w", calcEnd) = 1 Then
        ' Sat or Sun: add 2 days
        calcEnd = DateAdd("d", 2, calcEnd)
    End If
    
    EndDayTime = calcEnd

    GoTo Ret
    
Hell:
    EndDayTime = Err.Description
Ret:
    
End Function
```

You can then use it in your worksheet as follows:
[image: EndDayTime in column C]
In this example, I have a DateTime I've entered into A2, a number of hours into B2...B8, and column C has the EndDayTime function using Ax and Bx. In column A after row 2, it just copies C[row - 1] so the previous end becomes the next start

Cheers -

EDIT: Corrected code for end time of 17 not 18.

Comment: Rereading, I see I got the end hour wrong. Just change the code from endHour = 18 to endHour = 14, and calcEnd = DateAdd("h", 14, calcEnd) to calcEnd = DateAdd("h", 15, calcEnd). You should also change the comment....

Comment: can you help me again? I never did any VBA programming so i dont know how to adapt your code myself. Currently, when I use your function this happens:   

08-05-15 09:00 9 08-05-15 18:00

However, tomorrow is a saturday, so i want it to change to 11-05-15 9:00

Besides, do you know if its possible to work also with minutes? so when I add 4,5 hours it should add 4:30? Sorry for my unclear initial question! 

And thanks in advance!

Comment: If you put in 4.5 it should work properly. You need to change the end time from 18 to 17 as I said in my previous comment. Code is now edited for correct end time.

Comment: Great! I had one last issue and solved it myself. When the end time is set on 17, the end time can get over 17:00 (so 17:20) When the end time is set on 16 this issue is solved! many many thanks!

Comment: well I thoughed it worked: but when i add  6,4 to 
  
08-05-15 16:07 i get 11-05-15 13:07. So the function can calculate only with integers?

Comment: Look at the line where its checking whether or not the new end time is past the end of day. Work out what it's actually checking, and what it needs to check. Clue: with part hours in the mix, it needs to check a bit more!

Comment: I studied a little VBA and have tried to change the code for using minutes in stead of hours. so i changed the "h" to "n" and calculated start and end hour to start and end minutes (8*60=480 and15*60=960) However this dont work! can you see the problem?

Comment: You don't need to do that. Step back, and try to define the test: When the hour is > endHour, or the Hour is = endHour and ???? then it's past the end of the day'. Then write code to match the sentence.